# How can I write a function that returns a `dict` with key-value pairs defined in it's enclosing scope?

Tags: python

`get_dynamic_re` is a function that creates a `DynamicScope` object and returns it's memeber `d`, a `dict`.

How can I make it so `get_dynamic_re` passes key-value pairs to `DynamicScope`'s `d` so it returns a dictionary that has keys and values associated with the variables listed in `outer`?

Currently when I run the program I get a `KeyError`.

```
from collections.abc import Iterator, Mapping

def get_dynamic_re():
        ds = DynamicScope()
        return ds.d

class DynamicScope(Mapping):

    d = {}

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, __key: str) -> any: #gets an item from the dictionary
        if __key in self.d:
            return self.d[__key]

        else:
            raise NameError
    
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator: #iterates through the dictionary
        return self.d.__iter__()

    def __len__(self) -> int: #gets the length of the dictionary 
        return self.d.__len__()
```

```
def outer():
    a = "outer_a"
    b = "outer_b"
    c = "outer_c"
    return get_dynamic_re()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    dre = outer()
    print(f"{dre['a']=}")
    print(f"{dre['b']=}")
    print(f"{dre['c']=}")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "y", line 13, in <module>
    print(f"{dre['a']=}")
KeyError: 'a'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Not entirely sure what you're doing but you haven't set ```dre['a']``` anywhere..

Comment: A function gets access to nonlocal variables based on what it's nested inside, and access to global variables based on what module contains its definition.  It does not get *any* access to the variables of a function that merely calls it.  The calling function could grant access by passing `locals()` as a parameter, but note that this is generally read-only, and won't reflect any variables that changed values after `locals()` was called.

Comment: Hi @CodingMonster. Python does not implement dynamic scoping. LUT for variable names is created at compile time and assignment is done at runtime. Regardless of that, could you provide info about what `get_dynamic_re` does? As your code stands, the call to `outer` returns whatever `get_dynamic_re` returns. And as you haven't passed a, b or c  or `locals()` as parameters  (or any parameter for that matter) the only way that `dre` would have an 'a' key would be if  `get_dynamic_re` always returned a `Mapping` with an 'a' key in it.

Comment: This code does not define any function or class named `get_dynamic_re`...

Comment: Hi @JohnGordon `outer` function returns a call to `get_dynamic_re`. That's *why* I'm asking.

Comment: @JohnGordon @SilvioMayolo precisley that why I asked OP to provide info about what does `get_dynamic_re` returns

Comment: @HermanATN It's suppose to return a dictionary containing the variables in the reference environment but in a dynamically scoped order. I wasn't sure how to make it do that though which is what am I asking how to do.

Comment: I see `get_dynamic_re` in `outer()` but `dynamic_re` in your first code block - did you introduce a different function name by accident?

Comment: By the way, what's `abc.Mapping`? I'm trying to reproduce the code :P

Comment: @icedwater it's an abstract class. You can find it if you search for the python collections library. And yeah there should only be dynamic_re, my mistake

Comment: Hey @CodingMonster I've edited my answer to account for that function call mismatch and provide a solution with it's explanation. I've also submitted an edit to your question so its more clear how it can be answered but as it stands I don't have enough rep to re-open the question myself. Do take a look at the answer tho, I sincerely believe it could help you better understans both Python's scoping and an approach to your intended result. Hope it helps!

Comment: Also, don't give in to unhelpful and unkind comments. It seems is common -currency here to attack every newcomer that asks a question that can't be easily used to farm reputation, instead of trying to make the question better and provide an answer. I don't why SO has to be like this, but alas, you can find some nice people here amidst all those pedantic commentora.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, the reason `print(f"{dre['a']=}")` throws a `KeyError` is because whatever is returned by `outer` is in turn whatever is returned by `get_dynamic_re` - a function for which no signature nor implementation was given - but that returns *something* that does not have an 'a' Key. It seems that what you're trying to do is return a [`closure`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) with `outer`, in particular, a closure that further constructs and returns a `mapping` with Keys that correspond to `variables` in `outer`'s scope. Let's see...

### A word about Python variable scopes, lookups, locations and assignment

First and foremost Python **does not** implement dynamic scopes. Its model uses *lexical scoping* for variable lookups (*i.e.* the LUT for variable names is created at *compile-time*, and their scope is the block in which they're defined and those contained in it), but implements a *late binding* scheme: the name is looked up at *run-time*, when the code is used, not when it is defined and created.

As stated in the [Python's execution model docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html):

> A scope defines the visibility of a name within a block. **If a local
> variable is defined in a block, its scope includes that block. If the
> definition occurs in a function block, the scope extends to any blocks
> contained within the defining one**, unless a contained block introduces
> a different binding for the name.
>
> **When a name is used in a code block, it is resolved using the nearest
> enclosing scope.** The set of all such scopes visible to a code block is
> called the block’s environment.

So, for a `function` to be able to access some variable, that variable **must** be either:

- i) passed as a parameter to it; or
- ii) be *defined* in its enclosing scope.
  otherwise that `name` won't be found in the LUT for that function's scope, and a `NameError` exception will be raised.

Furthermore, **that variable must be assigned *before* the fuction tries to *use* it**, as binding happens at *run-time*, and missing the order would lead to an `UnboundLocalError` exception being raised.

For the sake of getting the *current* (*i.e.* the one in that scope block) table of pairs of names and references, Python provides the [built-in function `locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals), that updates and returns a dictionary representing LUT for that scope.

The function is *read-only* in the sense that modifying any of the variables or references does not modify them elsewhere in code, as described by the docs in [PEP 558](https://peps.python.org/pep-0558/#new-locals-documentation)

> At function scope (including for generators and coroutines), each call
> to `locals()` instead returns a fresh dictionary containing the current
> bindings of the function’s local variables and any non-local cell
> references. In this case, name binding changes made via the returned
> dict are not written back to the corresponding local variables or
> non-local cell references, and binding, rebinding, or deleting local
> variables and non-local cell references does not affect the contents of
> previously returned dictionaries.

### Why isn't `print(f"{dre['a']=}")` printing?

Well, now we know, variable named `a` is not accessible to `get_dynamic_re`, in fact, as `get_dynamic_re` is defined elsewhere outside `outer`, non of `outer`'s variables are within its reach. So, unless `get_dynamic_re` not only returns a `mapping`, but also one that already has an `a` Key, any statement that includes `dre['a']` will throw a `KeyError`.

### So how can we make it so that `get_dynamic_re` does return a `mapping` with Keys `a`,`b` and `c`?

**Well, we have 3 options:**

**1. Define `get_dynamic_re` inside `outer`:**

```
  def outer():
      a = "outer_a"
      b = "outer_b"
      c = "outer_c"
      def get_dynamic_re():
          ... 
          # return a mapping that has key associated with variables in outer's scope
          
      return get_dynamic_re()
```

**2. Pass variable dict with `locals`:**

```
  def outer():
      a = "outer_a"
      b = "outer_b"
      c = "outer_c"
      return get_dynamic_re(locals())
```

*Note that in this case `get_dynamic_re` should parse the `dict` given to it by `locals`*

**3. Pass variables by hand:**

```
  def outer():
      a = "outer_a"
      b = "outer_b"
      c = "outer_c"
      return get_dynamic_re(a,b,c)
```

Note that the three implementations of `outer` listed above *propagate* the return value of `get_dynamic_re`, so they're not (necessarily) returning a closure, and in the case that `get_dynamic_re` returns a `mapping`, assigning `dre = outer()`, makes `dre` a `mapping`, so `print(f"{dre['a']=}")` will in fact output *"dre['a']='outer_a'"* (provided that `get_dynamic_re`'s implementation add those keys to the `mapping`).

If the intention were to make `outer` return a closure, maybe one that takes some keyword arguments to further pass down to `get_dynamic_re`, that could be achieved by:

**4. Returning a closure**

```
  def outer(*, **kwargs): # * denotes keyword-only arguments
      a = "outer_a"
      b = "outer_b"
      c = "outer_c"
      def get_dynamic_re(**kwargs):
          ... 
          # construct and return a mapping using outer variables and **kwargs
      return get_dynamic_re # Notice that get_dynamic_re is not called
```

In that case `outer` would in fact return a *closure* so to instantiate and assign a `mapping` to a variable first we should retrieve the closure with a call to `outer` and then call it:

```
...
make_dre = outer(someKey="someValue",anotherKey="anotherValue")
dre = make_dre()
print(f"{dre['a']=}")
print(f"{dre['b']=}")
print(f"{dre['c']=}") 
print(f"{dre['someKey']=}")
print(f"{dre['someValue']=}")

>>> dre['a']='outer_a'
>>> dre['b']='outer_b'
>>> dre['c']='outer_c'
>>> dre['someKey']='someValue'
>>> dre['anotherKey']='anotherValue'
```

---

### A closer look to that `DynamicScope` class

You're kind of getting aroud to it, but as they've been written `DynamicScope` paired with `get_dynamic_re` don't do what your looking for. Let's break them down.

**`DynamicScope`s definition**

```
class DynamicScope(Mapping):

    d = {}

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass

    def __getitem__(self, __key: str) -> any: #gets an item from the dictionary
        if __key in self.d:
            return self.d[__key]

        else:
            raise NameError
    
    def __iter__(self) -> Iterator: #iterates through the dictionary
        return self.d.__iter__()

    def __len__(self) -> int: #gets the length of the dictionary 
        return self.d.__len__()
```

As `DynamicScope` is a subclass of `Mapping`, it would seem that the intended purpouse is for it to itself be a `Mapping`, but you've:

- i) Made a class attribute named `d`, a `dict` apart from `DynamicScope`'s elements;
- ii) overrided `__getitem__`, and `__iter__` so that trying to get an item from a `DynamicScope` instance or iterating over it, instead, performs those operations over the class member `d`; and
- iii) You haven't overrided the `__setitem__` method to be consistent with `__getitem__` and `__iter__`.

This has some particular implications: for starters, *altought `DynamicScope` is inheriting from `Mapping`, **it doesn't act as a `Mapping` but as a `wrapper` for a `dict` (in this case, class member `d`)***. More over, *all* instances of `DynamicScope` share *the same* `d`, as it is a class member, not an instance member. And, beacuase the interface is inconsistent (*i.e.* `__setitem__` would add an item to a  `DynamicScope` instance while `__getitem__` pulls one from the class member `d`) it's innefective both as a `Mapping` and as a `wrapper`, and using it as either one of those is going to produce some nasty, hard-to-debugg-and-track bugs.

This is easy to realize once you pair it with `get_dynamic_re`:

```
def get_dynamic_re():
        ds = DynamicScope() # creates a new DynamicScope object
        return ds.d # accesses and returns the dict inside it
```

As `DynamicScope` is merely a `wrapper` for a `dict`, `get_dynamic_re` (that's trying to return a dict) does not return the `DynamicScope` instance created **immediately before**, but it returns a reference to a plain-old `dict`, class member `d`. So, when using `get_dynamic_re` all that fancy subclassing from abstract classes and whatnot flies out of the window, and begs the question, why not use a simple `dict` instead of wrapping it in an object to immediately discard everything from that object except the `dict`?

Also, note that the reference returned by `get_dynamic_re` is not bound to a "new" `dict`, but to class memeber `d`, so any variable you assing using a call, *e.g.* `x = get_dynamic_re()`, is going to be referencing **the same** object, `DynamicScope.d`.

Furthermore, remember how it was stated that `DynamicScope`'s interface was *inconsistent*? Well, if you tried to set items for `DynamicScope` instead of setting them for `DynamicScope.d`, those items *won't* be part of `d`, and as you've `overrided` method `__getitem__` for `DynamicScope`, you won't have any way of accesing them.

```
def get_dynamic_re(outerVariables : dict): #assume your passing locals() when callign from outer
 
        ds = DynamicScope() # creates a new DynamicScope object
        for key,value in outerVariables:
          ds[key] = value   # set key-value pair to DynamicScope Mapping

        return ds.d # accesses and returns the dict inside it 
                    # d does not have the keys added above
                    # trying to acces it would raise a KeyError
dre = outer()
print(dre['a']) 
>> KeyError
```

Of course, you could "solve" this by setting those key-value pairs to `d` instead:

```
def get_dynamic_re(outerVariables : dict): #assume your passing locals() when callign from outer
 
        ds = DynamicScope() # creates a new DynamicScope object
        for key,value in outerVariables:
          ds.d[key] = value   # set key-value pair to member `d`

        return ds.d 
dre = outer()
print(dre['a']) 
>> 'outer_a'
```

But that just poses again the question ***why bother making `DynamicScope` in the first place?*** Also now every call to `get_dynamic_re` assings again and again key-value pairs to the same dict `d` (as it is a class member, not an instance member) in spite of a new instance of `DynamicScope` being created everytime. So:

- i) assigning two (or more) variables with `outer` or `get_dynamic_re` will make it so those variables **point to the same object**, and modifying one would mean modifying the other; and
- ii) if you, elsewere in code, should modify any of the values mapped to those keys, calling `get_dynamic_re` again would erase that.

### So, if not a `wrapper` class, what could we use?

Well... what about a closure that returns a plain-old `dict`? With what we've learnd thus far, a possible implementation of the task coulde be:

```
    def outer(*, **kwargs): # * denotes keyword-only arguments
        a = "outer_a"
        b = "outer_b"
        c = "outer_c"
        def get_dynamic_re(**kwargs):
            d = {}     # create a new dict
            d['a'] = a # access enclosing-scope variables
            d['b'] = b
            d['c'] = c
            for key,value in kwargs:
              d[key] = value   # set key-value pair from kwargs to `d`
            return d
        return get_dynamic_re # Notice that get_dynamic_re is not called
```

Here, every call to `outer` returns a `closure`, that in turn returns a **new** `dict` that has key-values pairs for both `outer`'s variables and the `**kwargs` passed to `outer`.

It can be used as follows:

```
  ...
  make_dre1 = outer(someKey="someValue1",anotherKey="anotherValue1")
  dre1 = make_dre1()
  print(f"{dre1['a']=}")
  print(f"{dre1['b']=}")
  print(f"{dre1['c']=}") 
  print(f"{dre1['someKey']=}")
  print(f"{dre1['anotherKey']=}")

  make_dre2 = outer(someKey="someValue2",anotherKey="anotherValue2",yetAnotherKey="yeyAnotherValue")
  dre2 = make_dre2()
  print(f"{dre2['a']=}")
  print(f"{dre2['b']=}")
  print(f"{dre2['c']=}") 
  print(f"{dre2['someKey']=}")
  print(f"{dre2['AnotherKey']=}")
  print(f"{dre2['yetAnotherKey']=}")


>>> dre1['a']='outer_a'
>>> dre1['b']='outer_b'
>>> dre1['c']='outer_c'
>>> dre1['someKey']='someValue1'
>>> dre1['anotherKey']='anotherValue1'

>>> dre2['a']='outer_a'
>>> dre2['b']='outer_b'
>>> dre2['c']='outer_c'
>>> dre2['someKey']='someValue2'
>>> dre2['anotherKey']='anotherValue2'
>>> dre2['yetAnotherKey']='yetAnotherValue'
```

Notice that in the above example both `dre1` and `dre2` have the same key-value pairs for `a`, `b` and `c`, as those are set from `outer`'s local variables, but have different key-value pairs for those that were passed as `**kwargs`

More over, new calls to both `make_dre1` and `make_dre2` won't return *the same* `dict` as before but a new one, that has all those keys, so modifying a `dict` that was created using them does not modify prior `dicts` nor "resets" them.